# Changing the screen width a nav bar collapses at with a centered heading

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, media-queries, nav

I have a centered heading within a nav which causes the links in the nav to wrap before the nav-bar collapes -

[image]

What I'd like to do is just have the links collapse earlier than they currently are. I've looked over all the answers to this question and haven't been able to find an answer that works for what I'm trying to accomplish. Down below is my last test. I thought if I changed the width of the custom header using a media query that would help but it hasn't. As of right now when the links collapse the hamburger icon is also floating to the left of the centered text. I'll worry about that later.

```
<nav class ="navbar navbar-expand-xl navbar-light bground">
            <a class ="navbar-brand" href ="#"> NavBar Testing </a>
            <button class ="navbar-toggler" type ="button" data-toggle ="collapse" data-target ="#colNav">
                <span class ="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="customHead">
                <text>Centered horizontally and vertically</text>
             </div> 

            <div class ="collapse navbar-collapse" id ="colNav">
                <ul class ="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class ="nav-item">
                        <a class ="nav-link" href="#"> Services </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class ="nav-item">
                        <a class ="nav-link" href ="#"> About Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class ="nav-item">
                        <a class ="nav-link" href ="#"> Contact Us </a>
                    </li>
                </ul> 
            </div>
        </nav>
```

```
.navbar-collapse {
    background-color: red;
    float: right;
    width: 25%;
}

.navbar-nav,  .nav-link{
    background-color: yellow;
    color: red !important;    
}

.customHead {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background: red;
  }
  
  text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -130%);
    background: orange;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .customHead {
        width: 80%;
    }
    .navbar-toggler {
        background-color: red;
        float: right;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is other CSS than what's displayed here so it's tough to know exactly. But one solve could be:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      .flex {
        flex: 1;
        display: flex;
      }

      .horizontal-center {
        justify-content: center;
      }

      .horizontal-end {
        justify-content: flex-end;
      }

      .vertical-center {
        align-items: center;
      }

      .navbar-nav {
        display: flex;
      }

      .nav-link{
          background-color: yellow;
          color: red !important;
          margin-left: 10px;
      }

      li {
        list-style: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="flex">
      <div class="flex vertical-center">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#colNav">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> NavBar Testing </a>
      </div>

      <div class="flex vertical-center horizontal-center">
        <text>Centered horizontally and vertically</text>
      </div>

      <div class="flex horizontal-end vertical-center">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> Services </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> Contact Us </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should've included my entire html. Thought it would be easier to troubleshoot if I kept my snippets small. I'll try out your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for keeping the navbar aligned correctly. Thanks! Still needs to work on collapsing the the links but this is a good start for me.